# ajax records in a selector

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I do not really know what terminology to call this but its just that am stock with my school assignment. This is what I want to do

I have  a code like this

`<information user_number_random="12345678"  />`. Now I want to periodically/dynamically change the `user_number_random` values by making ajax call to php file eg. **user.php** each time page is being refreshed.

```
<?php
$u_id=rand(0000,9999);
echo $u_id;
?>
```

below is my ajax call

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#btn').click(function(){ 

$.ajax({    

    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'user.php',
   data : $(this).serialize(),
    success : function(data)
    {
    $("#record").html(data);

    }
});
});
});

</script>
```

below is how am trying to get the ajax record values passed to **user_number_random** but its not showing anything. can someone help me fix that. Thanks

```
 <information user_number_random="record"  />
```

Comment: [**event.preventDefault()**](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: `$("#record")` targets an element having the value of `id` attribute as `record`. You probably want to use `$("information").attr('user_number_random', data)`

Comment: how do Implement  your solution. if  I say <div id="record"></div> , it will show the result but i need to supply the result to/directly to user_number_random, so how do I achieve data.

Comment: how do Implement  your solution. if  I say <div id="record"></div> , it will show the result but i need to supply the result to/directly to user_number_random, so how do I achieve data.

Comment: <information user_number_random="record"  /> what kind of tag it is ?

Comment: @ abhishekkannojia where can I add this your solution in the code above

Comment: Change your line `$("#record").html(data);` to `$("information").attr('user_number_random', data)` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible solution:**

```
<information user_number_random="record" />

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function(e) { 
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({    
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'user.php',
        success: function(data) {
          $("information").attr("user_number_random", data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

---

**Explanation:**

```
$('#btn').click(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
```

The `click` event passes in an "event object" to to event handler function, which we receive as **`e`**. Normally, when you click on a link, the browser loads the URL provided in the `href` attribute of the link, or simply reloads the page if an empty `href` is given. To prevent this *default action*, we call `e.preventDefault` on the event object. This way the page won't reload when you click the link.

I removed the `data: $(this).serialize()` property from your AJAX call, because you don't seem to need it in this case. You can use the `data` property to pass custom data attributes in the POST request to *user.php*. Any parameters you pass in there are made available in the `$_POST` array in your PHP code. Since you don't access `$_POST` in this case, you don't need to pass in any data attributes. And besides, `$(this).serialize()` only works when submitting forms, which is not the case here.

```
$("information").attr("user_number_random", data);
```

Since the HTML element you want to change is an `<information>` element, the jQuery selector needed to be adjusted accordingly. To set an attribute on an element, you can use `element.attr("attribute_name", "new_value")`.

Comment: I have tried it but what can I add here to output the record. i have added this to your code <information user_number_random="record"  /> but its not showing any record yet. I think the problem now is how to output the record or should i just say <information> to show the result

Comment: What happens when you click the button / link? Open up the developer tools in your browser, go to the _Network_ tab, and check if the AJAX call actually reaches **user.php**.

Comment: am checking it now

Comment: nothing is shown in the console using <information user_number_random="record" />  but  if i use <div id="record"></div>, it displays result